# How to style checkbox using CSS without :checked

Tags: css, checkbox, radio-button

All the answers in [How to style checkbox using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css) rely on the `:checked` pseudo-class selector. Since this selector is [**not supported by about half of the mobile browsers**](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/mobile.html), those are currently not useful answers.

So how can you style a checkbox or radio button with CSS (no JS!) **without the :checked pseudo-class selector**?

Comment: Wasn't this question answered in the 'Older Answer' section of the accepted answer for [How to style checkbox using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css)

Comment: @Joe The first old answer doesn't work in most browsers, the second uses JS. Or did I overlook something?

Comment: The point of that answer is that there is no cross-browser method for styling the box.  The :checked pseudo-class makes some stride in that direction, but even it is not universally supported.  Your only sure-fire method will be to use some javascript.

Answer (score 1):

**http://jsbin.com/rahuq/1/**

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked{
  outline: 2px solid red;
}
```

Tested in Android 2.3 and 4.3 and worked pretty well :)

If you really want to style it you can do like:
**http://jsbin.com/mikul/1/**

```
<input id="ch1" type="checkbox"><label for="ch1"></label>
```

```
input[id^=ch]{
  display:none;
}
input[id^=ch] + label{
  display:inline-block;
  width:16px;
  height:16px;
  background:green;
  border-radius:50%;
}
input[id^=ch]:checked + label{
  background: red;
}
```

Also tested in Android 2.3 and 4.3
Also tested in Firefox Mobile browser and works
Also tested in Chrome Mobile and native browsers

---

Upload by Roko

[image]
[image]

Edit by @what:

Here's a screenshot from Firefox for Android that shows that this does not work in that browser:
Upload by @what

[image]

Comment: @what looks like I'm the only one doing tests here. It works.

Comment: @what I have samsung galaxy S3 and it works bro, even on HTC Desire

Comment: It works in Android default browser, but it does **not** work on Firefox for Andorid (28.0.1) on my Samsung Galaxy S III

Comment: @what I have also 28.0.1 and works perfectly. Strange. Tap harder it changes color

Comment: I posted a screenshot as an edit to your post. Accept or delete as you wish. I *did* tap hard ;-)

Comment: +1 for trying to help me, Roko, but I feel I don't want to trust this selector.

Comment: @what do as you like, I attached my screenshots.

Comment: @what maybe you should check browser settings. because it is working fine for roko.

Comment: Yes, @Mr_Green, I see (and I believed him even without the screenshots). But I don't know what kind of browser setting would cause this behavior. I use FF as I installed it, and I'm sure most users don't change those settings either, so quite obviously **this solution cannot be relied on**. I cannot ask my users to check their browser settings, that is not a viable design solution. Also we are only talking about FF here. PPK lists several other browsers. Do they also work for you?